# Where does the 'Natural Language' rule come from?

Tags: dnd-5e

Frequently it is said (sometimes by me) that 5e's rules expect the reader to use 'natural language' or the 'normal' meaning of words when interpreting any words in the rules texts the game doesn't specifically define.  Where does this idea come from?  If it is a rule, where is it found?

Comment: Related (possibly dupe): [What is the source for 5e defaulting to plain English readings of non-game terms?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/135039)

Comment: If there was a rule, what language would you use to interpret it?